# Finding Specific Duplicate Text/Strings in Two Different Cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, macros

I had a quick question regarding how I might find exact duplicate text/strings using a formula or macro. Here are two of my columns for example:

[image: Two Columns to Compare]

With those columns in mind, I would like to have a third column next to them that runs a formula or macro which finds and prints the duplicates between T1 and T2. For instance, the third column for the values in that picture should return:

- 45
- 39, 60
- 
- 60
- 39, 60
- 
- 47

Answer (score 1):

Another option of

- adopt FILTERXML() and using Xpath to extract the duplicated number,
- INDEX() to force the array formula into non-array formula,
- TEXTJOIN() to join the extracted numbers,
- finally, to use IFERROR() to remove the error into blank cell.

In C2, formula copied down :

```
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(", ",1,INDEX(FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2&", "&B2,", ","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[preceding::b =.+0]"),0)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: It is still an array formula just does not require the use of Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  And if one is using Office 365 the CSE is no longer needed anyways.  So using INDEX for this is a dying need and just adds one more level of complexity.  But nice way of using FILTERXML to itself to return the duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

use SUBSTITUTE to create a XML like string.  Then use FILTERXML to return an array of the parts in one of the cells.  Use SEARCH with that array on the other.  Finally return the values that are found to TEXTJOIN:

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(","&TRIM(FILTERXML("<z><y>" & SUBSTITUTE(B2,",","</y><y>")&"</y></z>","//y"))&",",","&SUBSTITUTE(A2," ","")&",")),TRIM(FILTERXML("<z><y>" & SUBSTITUTE(B2,",","</y><y>")&"</y></z>","//y")),""))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Scott! I tried both formulas mentioned here, by you and the other user (bosco_yip), and they both worked flawlessly. I was wondering if you also might know how to compare T1 and T2 to detect omissions (from T1 to T2) and additions (from T1 to T2). So for example, T1 to T2 for the first row would have an addition of "67" returned in one column and then "47, 52" as omissions in another column. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: New questions get new posts.  Please ask a new question.